# Are strupr() and strlwr() in string.h part of the ANSI standard?

Tags: c, string.h

I was looking for this on internet and in every place with the functions of string.h these two are not mentioned.

Is because what? They aren't in every compiler?

Comment: Related (if not a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/q/23618316/694576

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They are non-standard functions from Microsoft's C library.  MS has since deprecated them in favor of renamed functions `_strlwr()` and `_strupr()`:

- [`strlwr()` doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strlwr-wcslwr)
- [`strupr()` doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strupr-wcsupr)

Note that the MS docs claim they are POSIX functions, but as far as I can tell they never have been.

If you need to use them on a non-MS toolchain, they're easy enough to implement.

```
char* strlwr(char* s)
{
    char* tmp = s;

    for (;*tmp;++tmp) {
        *tmp = tolower((unsigned char) *tmp);
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: They're also supported by gcc, even if you try to force standards-compliance with something like `-std=c11`.

Comment: Regarding them being POSIX functions - there's a searchable online version of POSIX.1-2017 hosted at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ - and they're definitely not mentioned in it.

Comment: Also, you might want to add `#include <ctype.h>` in that code snippet, since `tolower` needs it and `strlwr` needed `<string.h>` instead.

Comment: `_strlwr` and `_strupr` will illicit compiler warning C4996 (Your code uses a function, class member, variable, or typedef that's marked deprecated) in Visual Studio 2022 which suggests using `_strlwr_s`, `_strupr_s` instead.

Comment: The MS docs linked do **not** claim these are Posix functions, but 'Microsoft specific'. The `_strlwr` page doesn't mention Posix at all, and the `strlwr` page mentions it in connection with renaming the function, and links to a page with this remark: *Microsoft renamed some POSIX and Microsoft-specific library functions in the CRT to conform with...* The renaming concerned both MS and Posix functions which are not part of the C sttandard.

Answer (score 5):

These functions are not C standard functions. So it is implementation-defined whether they are supported or not.

Answer (score 2):

These functions are not standard, and in fact their signatures are broken/non-usable. You cannot case-map a string in-place in general, because the length may change under case mapping.