# compilation error: conflicting types for 'modify' - why?

Tags: c

Why am I getting compilation error for below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void modify(struct emp *y);
struct emp
{
  char name[20];
  int age;
};
main()
{
  struct emp e={"foo",35};
  modify(&e);
  printf("\n%s%d",e.name,e.age);
}
void modify(struct emp *p){
  strupr(p->name);
  p->age = p->age+2;
}
```

Below is the part of build log messages.

error: conflicting types for 'modify'| at line no. 15

note: previous declaration of 'modify' was here| at line no. 3

Comment: Is there also an error or a warning that `struct emp` is undefined or undeclared? Because that matters.

Comment: @Rhymoid No such warning like undefined or undeclared struct emp.

Answer (score 3):

gcc can tell you the reason.

Increase your warning level:

```
prog.c:3:20: warning: 'struct emp' declared inside parameter list
 void modify(struct emp *y);
                    ^
prog.c:3:20: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is 
                      probably not what you want
```

You can either change the order of the prototype and the struct definition, or add a declaration of the struct before the prototype.

Comment: Why the scope is limited to this prototype?

Comment: Because it has no other way to sensibly fix your broken code. C is read from front to back. If the compiler is missing information, it can't look ahead.

Comment: @VaibhavGautam Because that's the rule. If you want to know why that's the rule, the ANSI committee may have an archive of discussions somewhere.

Comment: @Rhymoid So basically compiler is considering two different instances of struct emp, and when it sees that instance of struct in calling function argument does not match with instance of struct during function prototype, it gives conflicting type error.

Comment: That's how I understand the situation. Always make sure to declare everything upfront, and to instruct your compiler to warn you about every problem (for GCC, you need the `-Wall -pedantic` flags, and using `-Werror` is a good habit to get used to).

Answer (score 1):

Move the struct upwards so your function prototype knows `emp`

```
    struct emp
    {
      char name[20];
      int age;
    };
    void modify(struct emp *y);    

    int main(void)
    {
      struct emp e={"foo",35};
      modify(&e);
      printf("\n%s%d",e.name,e.age);
      return 0;
    }
    void modify(struct emp *p){
      p->age = p->age+2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of `main()` is incorrect. The function [should return an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c): `return 0;`, and the return type should be specified explicitly:

```
int main(void)
{
  /* ... */
  return 0;
}
```

Prototype of `modify` function mentions undeclared structure `emp`. In other words, you should put the declaration of `emp` structure before the prototype.

Avoid using `strupr` as it [is non-standard function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327812/strupr-and-strlwr-in-string-h-part-are-of-the-ansi-standard/26328095#26328095).

Consider declaring functions `static`, if they are supposed to be used *only* within the current compilation unit.

Comment: You're wrong about the definition of `main`. It's the one function that does not need an explicit return statement.

Comment: @Rhymoid, okay, it _should_ explicitly return integer, and the return type _should_ be specified.

Comment: Regarding rants and incorrect believes about the format of `main`, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518). `main()` is valid in C90 and also on all freestanding implementations. Missing `return 0` is undefined behavior in C90 but valid in later standards.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov IIRC, it's implicit, and _should_ is valid only if you expect something other than `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the definitions around will fix the issue for you. But since no one mentioned it yet, I'll pitch in:

You can fix it with the minimal change of forward declaring the `struct`.

```
struct emp; // Forward declare struct emp before using it in the prototype.
void modify(struct emp *y);
```