# uppercase a character in c

Tags: c, uppercase

I want the the letter "i" to show as uppercase. I have tried to pass the "i" to another char, it is still not working.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char str[6] = "modify";
    char maj = str[4];

    printf("%c\n", strupr (maj));

}
```

Comment: Change that to char str[7] or simply char str[]. You need an extra byte for the '\0' null terminator

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings for a start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `strupr`. You need `toupper()` instead, and that needs `#include<ctype.h>`

Comment: Isn't it possible with "strupr"? Because i have been looking some examples and poeple made it using "strupr".

Comment: @Abdullah that was Microsoft stuff and also had been obsolete:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327812/strupr-and-strlwr-in-string-h-part-are-of-the-ansi-standard

Comment: you'd better off sticking with standard function

Comment: @Abdullah: *of course* it's possible with a function such as `strupr`, but it works on *entire strings* (so you'd have to make your single character into a valid string) ... but for a single character, just use `toupper()`.