# Using toupper with a structure in C

Tags: c, structure, toupper

What I am trying to do is to have the user input their information.  Like state for example.  I need to process this state abbreviation and output it as capital letters.  I'm confused at how to do that because I am using structures. When I use what I am using below it tells me they are incompatible and it doesn't work.  What should I do differently.  I've tried pretty much everything.  This is in C.

```
for (i = 0; i < 3 != '\0'; i++) {
    people[i].state = toupper(people[i].state);
}
```

Comment: `i < 3 != '\0'` what is this?

Comment: `toupper()` works on one character at a time.  It's hard to be sure because you haven't given the definition of your structure, but it looks like you're trying to apply it to a whole string.

Comment: @SouravGhosh The fanciest way to check if `i` is less than `3` I've seen so far.

Comment: @EugeneSh. True, but I still suspect that wasn't the intent of that code.  Ouch.

Comment: For future questions, not that *Using `toupper()` with a structure* has no reason to be something special, `toupper()` takes a character and returns the *upper*case of it and that's all. It doesn't care where did the character come from.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you mean the following

```
for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
    for ( char *p = people[i].state; *p; ++p ) *p = toupper( ( unsigned char )*p );
}
```

Or if you have a single object of the structure type then something like

```
for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
    people.state[i] = toupper( ( unsigned char )people.state[i] );
}
```

or even

```
for ( i = 0; i < 3 && people.state[i] != '\0'; i++ )
{
    people.state[i] = toupper( ( unsigned char )people.state[i] );
}
```

Comment: @J.Piquard It is not standard C function.

Comment: @J.Piquard Ref: [strupr() and strlwr() in string.h part are of the ANSI standard?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26327812/2410359)

Comment: When I put any of these in it gives me an error that says  [Error]: incompatible types in assignment

Comment: @Drew  What are the types of  people and state?

Comment: @vladfromMoscow They are a type of character in a structure.  I need to output it as two capital letters.
  <pre> <code>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <ctype.h>

     struct info
     {
     char full_name[35];
     char address [50];
     char city [25];
     char state [3];
     long int zip_code;
     int age;
     }

    int main()
    {
 
     for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
       {
         people[i].state = toupper(people[i].state);
      }