# Standard functions in C99 being called "Implicit declarations"

Tags: c, pid, execv

I have a C program that I am running on my MacOS terminal. All command line tools and GCC compiler have been installed. However for using functions like `getpid()` or `execv()` it gives **the following error**:

```
execv-test.c:7:35: error: implicit declaration of function 'getpid' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        printf("Pid before execv: %d\n", getpid());
                                         ^
execv-test.c:8:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'execv' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        execv("print",NULL);
        ^
2 errors generated.
```

**The code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
        printf("The game is never over, John. But there may be some new players now.\n");
        printf("Pid before execv: %d\n", getpid());
        execv("print",NULL);
        printf("Returned from execv call.\n");
        return 0;
}
```

The following [Stack Overflow exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920618/unable-to-get-rid-of-errors-even-after-using-the-right-headers) suggested that I write helper functions for the ones that were taken as implicit declarations. However, I am not sure you could do the same with `getpid()` or `execv()`. What should I do to make sure this doesn't happen?

**PLEASE NOTE**: "print" is just another helper file that is supposed to be run once `execv()` is called.

Comment: Prototype for [`getpid()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpid.html) is in `<unistd.h>` (same for [`execv()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html)). Note these are not plain C functions: they are a POSIX extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you are using system calls that are defined in the `unistd.h` header file. Therefore calling them without including the std library `#include <unistd.h>` amounts to "implicit declaration" = "calling a function without defining it first".

Comment: And may I just add, C89 would instead go "huh, getpid(), never heard of that before. Lets assume it is a function returning int and run anyway." Which would kind of suck if it was actually a function returning something else other than int (`malloc` springs to mind). This was a major design flaw in C89 that C99 corrected.