# In 'C', Linux, how can I interrupt a while() loop, not knowing if or when the interrupt will occur

Tags: c, loops, interrupt

I'm looking for a method to 'interrupt' a loop construct in my program.
Inside a while(1) loop, there is STDIN input.  Only when input occurs,
does the loop continue.  I've been looking at threads, signals and other
possible ways to make this work.  I'm not sure what is better suited.
The code shows a function to check for the presence of a file.  If
found, I hope to make further decisions on that event.  Does the
BLOCKING nature of fscanf() nullify any thread or signal method?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>     //  for sleep()

int main(void);
int filefound(void);

int filefound()  {
    //  code to look for a file
    //  if found, return 'true'

    return(false);      //      file not found
    }

int main()    {
    char    instring[25];

    while (1)  {
        printf("\nType bad words:  ");

        fscanf(stdin, "%[^\n]%*c", instring);

        if (filefound() == true)
            printf("\nFILE FOUND\n");

        printf("\nPotty mouth...\n");
        sleep(3);
        }

    return(0);
    }
```

Continuing research and trial/error.

Comment: Well, what happens when you try using signals?

Comment: Explain what you want to achieve.  Your question is very unclear

Comment: You can create a signal handler for `SIGINT`. Then the user can type Ctl-c to interrupt the loop.

Comment: @gandsnut, Note: `fscanf(stdin, "%[^\n]%*c", instring);` risk overflow.  Better as `fscanf(stdin, "%24[^\n]%*c", instring);`.

Comment: `if (filefound() == true)` is strange.  Better as `bool filefound(...)  if (filefound())`

Comment: My simplistic code actually does not involve USER input; rather, what fscanf() receives via STDIN is from an external program PIPING into this program.  Were my code compiled to executable 'monitor', it is attached to other program, say, 'network_traffic', in this fashion:    "network_traffic | monitor".   If adding SIGNAL mechanisms will introduce an interrupt when fscanf() is awaiting input via the pipe, that would greatly help.  I'll see about adding signal handling.  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop an infinite loop (or any loop construct) in C in several ways from less drastic to more drastic:

### Statements that break out of loops

1. `continue;` - this statement doesn't actually stop the loop, it stops the current iteration. It's useful for when the current iteration should be skipped for any reason.
2. `break;` - this statement on its own will immediately stop the loop and continue from the line right after the loop's end.
3. `goto LABEL;` - This one is one you should avoid as much as possible. It's an unconditional jump out of your code into another place in the program. It's *usually* considered bad practice. But, there IS one instance where it's still argued to be the appropriate choice, breaking out of nested loops more simply than having an "exit flag" that can be set which then breaks each level of looping. You set a label after all the nested loops, and then `goto` that label under any conditions in which all the loops should stop.
4. `return;` - this statement will not only break out of the loop, but the whole function stops and whatever value is put after it will be returned to the caller. This means that doing `int x = function()` will cause `x` to be the returned value from `function()` assuming that `function()` is declared as `int function()`
5. `exit();` - this will end the program. You will need to have <stdlib.h> included before you can use it.

### For your specific case

In your case, you would probably want a line somewhere in your loop, probably the end, like the first example below, however, you could also change the condition itself or use a `do...while` loop if the loop must execute at least once:

### Break at the end:

```c
#include <string.h>
...
while (1) {
    ...
    if (strncmp(strupr(instring), "EXIT") == 0) break;
}
```

### Change the Condition

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LENGTH 25
...
char instring[LENGTH];
memset(instring, 0, LENGTH * sizeof(char));
...
while (strcmp(strupr(instring), "EXIT") != 0) {
    ...
}
```

### Use a do-while loop

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LENGTH 25
...
char instring[LENGTH];
memset(instring, 0, LENGTH * sizeof(char));
...
do {
    ...
} while (strcmp(strupr(instring), "EXIT") != 0)
```

Any of these will accomplish what you're asking for in the most optimal way possible. In fact it wouldn't surprise me if, once optimized, they all result in the same or nearly the same machine code.

### Explanation

- `strcmp(const char * first, const char * second)` compares two strings - `first` and `second` - and returns a positive or negative number, or zero. When it returns zero, the strings are identical.
- `strupr(char * str)`[1] changes a string `str` to uppercase and then returns a pointer to the modified string.
- `memset(char * buffer, int value, size_t length)` sets `length` bytes of memory from the pointer `buffer` to be the value `value`. In this case, write all 0's to the array used to store user input.

[1]: This function only works on Microsoft based systems. So to mitigate that, I've included this snippet you can put at the top of your code to define the function using standard library functions if you're not on windows.

```c
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__) || defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(__BORLANDC__)
char * strupr(char * buffer) {
    for (int i = 0; true; i++) {
        if (buffer[i] == '\0') return buffer;
        buffer[i] = (char)toupper(buffer[i]);
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Where is `strupr()` defined? Is it an extension of Microsoft?

Comment: @Harith See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26327812/10871073

Comment: @AdrianMole Microsoft's, as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Good catch! I didn't realize that was a microsoft specific function when I googled it. I've added a snippet you can add to implement the function if the code is being compiled in an environment where it doesn't exist. Thanks guys for pointing that out so I could make my answer even better. I hope it's helpful for anyone who has the same question.