# Location of strlen-avx2.S & help recreating strlwr()

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to compile my homework and I needed to recreate `strlwr()` (only available on Windows), and I'm getting this error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:65
65      ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S: No such file or directory.
```

I'm using [this](http://www.howtobuildsoftware.com/index.php/how-do/coIP/c-string-reference-undefined-lowercase-undefined-reference-to-strlwr) `strlwr()`.

I [found the code for strlen-avx2.S](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S.html), but I can't find it in my system.

If I use [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23618467/8666827), there's no mention of strlen-avx2.S, but still getting segmentation fault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555532d in strlwr (str=0x0) at parser.c:36
36              while (*p) {
```

Comment: `str=0x0`: You have called your `strlwr` function with a null pointer instead of a valid string.  It's not written to handle that.  Either don't do that, or else add the appropriate check.

Comment: That's not a good implementation of `strlwr()` — it scans the string twice when once is sufficient.  Consider: `char *strlwr(char *str) { for (char *p = str; *p != '\0'; p++) *p = tolower((unsigned char)*p); return str; }` — the cast is a good (necessary) feature of the code (in the original that I'm deconstructing and reconstructing).