# how to fix these 2 errors? ‘strlwr’ - 'but argument 2 has type ‘int’'

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors

I'm a beginner in the field and I have a question regarding my code. These two errors are showing up:

- main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
  main.cpp:118:39: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int*’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
- main.cpp:161:56: error: ‘strlwr’ was not declared in this scope

I can't fix it, can someone help me?
my code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>

#include <conio.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <locale.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

typedef struct carro

{

    int cod;

    char marca[20];

    char modelo[20];

    int ano;

    char placa[10];

} carro;

carro car[10];

void menu();

void inicializar();

void imprimir();

void cadastrar();

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");

    int i;

    int op;

    int ano;

    int z;

    char modelo[20];

    z = 0;

    ano = 0;

    i = 0;

    car[i].cod = 0;

    strcpy(car[i].marca, "NULL");

    strcpy(car[i].modelo, "NULL");

    strcpy(car[i].placa, "NULL");

    car[i].ano = 0;

    do

    {

        printf("\n Opções:");

        printf("\n 1. CADASTRAR VEÍCULO");

        printf("\n 2. LISTAR VEÍCULOS");

        printf("\n 3. PESQUISAR UM MODELO");

        printf("\n 4. MOSTRAR VEÍCULOS A PARTIR DE UM ANO");

        printf("\n 5. SAIR");

        printf("\n \n DIGITE A OPÇÃO: ");

        scanf("%d", &op);

        switch (op)

        {

        case 1:

            if (car[i].cod <= 9)

            {

                car[i].cod = i;

                printf("\n Digite a marca do veículo:");

                scanf("%s", car[i].marca);

                printf("\n Digite o modelo do veículo:");

                scanf("%s", car[i].modelo);

                printf("\n Digite a placa do veículo:");

                scanf("%s", car[i].placa);

                printf("\n Digite o ano do veículo:");

                scanf("%d", car[i].ano);

                i = i + 1;
            }

            else

            {

                printf("\n Limite de cadastro é 10!");
            }

            break;

        case 2:

            for (int x = 0; x < i; x++)

            {

                printf("\n A marca do veículo é: %s", car[x].marca);

                printf("\n O modelo do veículo é: %s", car[x].modelo);

                printf("\n O ano do veículo é: %d", car[x].ano);

                printf("\n A placa do veículo é: %s", car[x].placa);

                printf("\n\n =================================== \n \n");
            }

            break;

        case 3:

            printf("\n   INSIRA O MODELO A SER PESQUISADO:");

            scanf("%s", modelo);

            for (int x = 0; x < i; x++)

            {

                if (strcmp(car[x].modelo, strlwr(modelo)) == 0)

                {

                    printf("\n A marca do veículo é: %s", car[x].marca);

                    printf("\n O modelo do veículo é: %s", car[x].modelo);

                    printf("\n O ano do veículo é: %d", car[x].ano);

                    printf("\n A placa do veículo é: %s", car[x].placa);

                    printf("\n\n =================================== \n \n");

                    z++;
                }
            }

            if (z == 0)

            {

                printf("\n NÃO FOI ENCONTRADO O MODELO %s \n\n", modelo);
            }

            else

            {

                z = 0;
            }

            break;

        case 4:

            printf("\n     INSIRA O ANO A SER PESQUISADO:");

            scanf("%d", &ano);

            for (int x = 0; x < i; x++)

            {

                if (car[x].ano >= ano)

                {

                    printf("\n A marca do veículo é: %s", car[x].marca);

                    printf("\n O modelo do veículo é: %s", car[x].modelo);

                    printf("\n O ano do veículo é: %d", car[x].ano);

                    printf("\n A placa do veículo é: %s", car[x].placa);

                    printf("\n\n =================================== \n \n");

                    z++;
                }
            }

            if (z == 0)

            {

                printf("\n NÃO FOI ENCONTRADO VEÍCULOS ACIMA DE %d \n\n", ano);
            }

            else

            {

                z = 0;
            }

            break;

        default:

            printf("\n Opção não existe");

            break;
        }

    }

    while (op != 5 && i <= 9);

    if (i == 9)

    {

        printf("\n \n LIMITE DE VEÍCULOS ALCANÇADO! \n \n \n");
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < i; y++)

    {

        printf("\n A marca do veículo é: %s", car[y].marca);

        printf("\n O modelo do veículo é: %s", car[y].modelo);

        printf("\n O ano do veículo é: %d", car[y].ano);

        printf("\n A placa do veículo é: %s", car[y].placa);

        printf("\n\n =================================== \n \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For the first, change `scanf("%d", car[i].ano);` to `scanf("%d", &car[i].ano);`. As suggested by the message, you need to give the *address* of the input variable, as you have done elsewhere.

Comment: For the second, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23618467/10871073) to "undefined reference to 'strlwr'".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you need to pass a pointer for scanf:

`scanf("%d", car[i].ano);` => `scanf("%d", &car[i].ano);`

[And the anser to your strlwr issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618316/undefined-reference-to-strlwr)